# Only one positive solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> When $(a+b)^2=(x-3a)(x-b)e^x$ has only one positive solution, find the relationship between a and b. Here, a and b are constants and satisfy $a>b>0$.
>
> Hint: consider the graph of $y=A\cdot e^{-x}$, where $A$ is constant.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQQwb.jpg

So far, I rearranged it so that

$$(a+b)^2e^{-x}=(x-3a)(x-b)$$

Since

$$A\cdot e^{-x}>0 ,$$

$$(x-3a)(x-b)>0.$$

Not sure what's next.

Comment: Since $a>b>0$ we have $3a>b>0$. So $(x−3a)(x−b)>0$ leads to $x>3a>0$ or $0<x<b$.